# Load files from base folder through a shortcut folder?

Tags: c#, .net, io, filesystems

brief:I have to servers working same application one of them will host some media files [mp4]
I need to play those media whatever I call the site from server 1 or server 2.

In details my site published on two different IIS servers one and I need to put a folder on IIS server 1 and could access the folder and it's content from the IIS server 2.

I try to put a shortcut on the server 2 that refer to the actual folder on server 1
No problem of course to open it throw the windows file system.

but how could I load the files from the actual folder trough the shortcut .. if it possible

**if not please advise me with a solution for such problem !?**

Answer (score 1):

Create a Virtual Folder to the folder on the other server.

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308150).

Answer (score 1):

If you can't create Virtual Directories in IIS, you can always create `NTFS Symbolic Links`. Read more about them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)